# Sending an AJAX post retrieves the whole PHP

Tags: php

Now before you say this one is duplicate, check my code below please:
function:

```
$.ajax
({
type: 'POST',
url: 'store.php',
data: $g,
success: function(response){alert(response);}
});
```

store.php:

```
<?php
    echo 'worked';
?>
```

Result: either no alert or

```
<?php
    echo 'worked';
?>
```

any advice?

Comment: Does the PHP file work if you access it directly through the web browser?

Comment: No, returns this: <?php
 echo 'worked';
?>

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with ajax, you need to make sure your web server is set up to serve PHP